# How can you register a callback with Popen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, callback

A friend was wanting to write some code so that after `Popen` finishes running, a callback is executed. Here is an example program of what is desired and should help with developing a proper answer:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen


def main():
    handle = Popen(('cmd', '/c', 'pause'))
    handle.register_callback(Popen, ('cmd', '/c', 'echo', 'THE END'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is the easiest way to provide a `register_callback` method in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to introduce another class that inherits from `Popen` and provides a `register_callback` method. The following program demonstrates how this is easily possible:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen
from threading import Thread


def main():
    handle = Process(('cmd', '/c', 'pause'))
    handle.register_callback(Process, ('cmd', '/c', 'echo', 'THE END'))


class Process(Popen):

    def register_callback(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread(target=self.__bootstrap, args=(callback, args, kwargs)).start()

    def __bootstrap(self, callback, args, kwargs):
        self.wait()
        callback(*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This answer may not be suitable for all applications but works in the given situation.

Comment: As soon as the `__bootstrap()` method is called, the main thread will block until the process terminates. If that's all you need to do, why don't you just call `self.wait()` (or `handle.wait()`) directly?

Comment: Maybe because this is a minimal example? It is conceivable that the code is simply representative of a much larger and complicated program where the `register_callback` method might actually be useful.

Comment: If there are additional constraints, you should outline them in the question (since you posted it, too).

Comment: @martineau Additional constraints would exceed the directive given here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid blocking the main thread's processing so it can do other things, you could create a separate thread the *polls* the process to see if it's done:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from threading import Thread
import time

class Process(Popen):
    def register_callback(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread(target=self._poll_completion, args=(callback, args, kwargs)).start()

    def _poll_completion(self, callback, args, kwargs):
        while self.poll() is None:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        callback(*args, **kwargs)

def main():
    handle = Process(('cmd', '/c', 'echo', 'process finished'))
    handle.register_callback(my_callback)

def my_callback():
    print("It's done!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```